# Redirect echom output in a function to a log file

Tags: vimrc

I would like to debug functions a bit more easily. Instead of running them and having to do:

```
:10 messages
```

To actually just have a `vim.log` file opened and tail -f'ed so I can see the output while it's running, without having to keep going into and out of messages and such.

Is there a way to do this? For example, in the following function:

```
func Toggle2 ()
    echom 'start toggle2...'
    echom 'end toggle2...'
endfunc
```

I would essentially like to do:

- Output goes to `vim.log` for this function
- But I don't want all the other vim-related messages. Just this function.

How could this be done? I tried doing the following:

```
func Toggle2 ()
    call execute('redir > vim.log')
    echom 'start toggle2...'
    echom 'end toggle2...'
    call execute('redir END')
endfunc
```

But received the following error:

> E930: Cannot use :redir inside execute()

Comment: You don't need `execute()` to do `:redir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As matt points our, just `redir`:

```
redir > file
"...
redir END
```

Answer (score 2):

The other possibility is to use a logging framework like [mine](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md).

When working on complex plugins for years it's really game changing. The main feature being:

- having the logs sent to the quickfix window with the file+line where the log has been done
- the possibility to choose which *module* is logging and which isn't (actually this is a consequence of how I use my logging framework) -- it works best, and very well, with autoload plugins that you haven't seen yet.

However, for your first plugins it may be a little overkill.

---

PS: I see `:redir` as the old solution which has few annoying drawbacks. I use it for portability issues when `execute()` isn't available. I even prefer `call writefile('filename', execute('message'))` -- I may have mixed-up the order of `writefile()` parameters.

PPS: I really feel like writing the same things over and over again. You really should avoid asking precisions on a topic in multiple questions

Comment: that's really cool (and incredible) that plugin. Inspired by that I tried writing a basic log function, which I've added a question about here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25936/getting-the-line-number-and-function-name-of-a-function-caller. How do you do introspection?