# Getting the line number and function name of a function caller

Tags: vimrc

I am writing a basic log function so that I can print debug output to a file (and perhaps more-so, to practice writing a function in vim). Here is where I am at right now:

```
let g:log_level_map = {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}
let g:log_level     = "DEBUG"

func LogOutput(msg, level='DEBUG')

    redir >> log.vim

    " Make sure its above the log_level
    if g:log_level_map[a:level] < g:log_level_map[g:log_level]
        return
    endif

    " _LogFormat: [TIME] LEVEL - FILE - FUNC - LINE : MSG
    let time = strftime('%c')
    let level = a:level
    let file = expand('%:p:t')
    let func = '' " how to get caller function?
    let line = '' " how to get caller line no?
    let msg = a:msg

    " Print the output
    echom(printf("[%s] %s - %s - %s- L%s : %s",
               \ time, level, file, func, line, msg))

    redir END

endfunc
```

It works great, but I'm having difficult figuring out how to get the line and function (if it exists) of the line of code that called the `LogOutput` function. Is it possible to access something like a call stack here, or how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

That's quite complex to do. [At this moment, vim offers no native way to do this correctly](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md).

I provide an API as good/correct as vim let me wrote, that I document [here](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md).

There are several steps and issues to be aware of.

1. First to know the current line number, we have to throw a dummy exception, and catch it to decode its `v:throwpoint`. And this will incur an important slow down of the execution if called often.
2. Then there are several problems

   - `v:throwpoint` is localized -- its exact value will differ from locale to locale (English, French, German...): there is a little localized `", line %d"` (IIRC) at the end.
   - While on *nix we can use *gettext* through bash to parse a localised message, Windows required other workarounds (like temporarily forcing the locale to C)
   - *script local functions* have mangled names
   - *anonymous functions* can be found thanks to `:verbose`, but again, the message will be localized (and knows small differences between Vim versions). Anonymous functions may also be discarded if the dictionary they belong to is garbage-collected. This is the most annoying issue with these function. Hence: [my one of my recommendation regarding how to do some OO programming in vimscript language](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/OO.md#avoid-anonymous-functions).
   - *autoloaded functions* contain `#` which may not belong to `'isk'` which may cause regex mismatch -- at least I had a few issues with this because I try to avoid parsing the result of `:verbose function .....` if I can.

In the end, I use my API for 4 things at this date:

- provide a logging framework
- provide a unit testing framework for vimscript language
- provide a DbC framework
- decode error messages

(See the link to the API for more regarding my use cases)

Comment: wow, that's really neat. Could you show a very basic example of manually throwing an error and then capturing it (without parsing the result, maybe just 2-4 lines of code I suppose)?

Comment: Without the locale issue, and throwing the dummy exception, the [decoding](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim#L58) is close to 70lines; and this is the really important part. Throwing the dummy exception, is just that (it's in the documentation of the API), and [just a few lines](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim#L150).

Comment: I see. So I've been able to capture `v:throwpoint`, but it's just telling me the function of the try/catch -- `function LogOutput, line 3` -- how do I grab the parent function/caller?

Comment: The simple answer: `exe "verbose function ".funcname"`. For a little bit more resilient answer, see previous link. Note: your use case is with a call depth of 1 -- only one function.

Comment: is `verbose function` in the above `"LogOutput"` or its a wrapper function that calls it?

Comment: also, for reference, this is very helpful (yours also) -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34078655/651174

Comment: It's a command -- hint: there are no parenthesis. And it's native -- hint: no `#`, nor capital letters. And I made mistake in the previous comment (one extra quote) -> given `funcname` variable == `'LogOutput'`, you'll need to capture `:exe ':verbose function '.funcname` -- I anticipate your next question about `:verbose function {How_do_I_pass_a_variable}` -> `:h :exe` and many Q/A here and on SO

Comment: well, here's the closest I get -- I pass an info dict, which isn't really introspection, but I think it's as far as my vim abilities allow me to go as of now -- `call LogOutput("some msg", 'DEBUG', {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})`.