# How to open a file in the last active gvim instance

Tags: gvim, tabbed-user-interface

I recently discovered `-p` and `--remote-tab`. Since I edit loads of files at the same time, sometimes with over 50 gvim instances open (and I am not a fan of buffers), I could use a bit of decluttering. However, at the same time, I don't want to push them all in a single instance. In other words, I want to open files in gvim tabs, but keep the ability to have multiple instances and control in which one I open any new file(s) I decide to open. That way I could group files in gvim instances the way I see fit.

My intended approach was to make two simple aliases in `.bashrc`:

```bash
alias gvim="gvim -p"
alias gvimt="gvim --remote-tab"
```

What I expected was that `gvim paths/to/some/files*` would open a new instance with those files in tabs, and that works as expected. However, I also expected `gvimt paths/to/some/files*` to do the same in my last active gvim instance, but that did not happen. Instead, it seems to pick some default instance (possibly the first one I opened; not sure).

How do I make `gvimt`, either through that alias or through `vimrc` settings (but, ideally, without vim plugins), open files in tabs of the last active instance ("window", in window manager terms) instead of whatever is the default?

**Maps**

For completeness, the following maps work nicely with the accepted solution below:

```
" Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab
map <C-Tab> gt
map <C-S-Tab> gT
map! <C-Tab> <C-O>gt
map! <C-S-Tab> <C-O>gT
```

These make `Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` behave as they usually do in editors (next/previous tab, respectively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Write the server's name to a file whenever Vim gets input focus**

```
function NameToFileWhenActive()
    redir! > ~/.vim.active| echon v:servername | redir END
endfunction
autocmd FocusGained * silent call NameToFileWhenActive()
```

The [`redir` line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/redirect-echom-output-in-a-function-to-a-log-file) simply writes the server's name to the file. It needs
to be in a function if we want to silence it (otherwise it pops up in the
last line every single time).

**The alias**

```
alias gvimt='gvim --servername "$(cat ~/.vim.active)" --remote-tab'
```

<sup>In Bash you can use its native construct `"$(<~/.vim.active)"` to avoid spawning a new process.</sup>

**Notes**

The documentation says FocusGained is only certain to work in Gvim, which you are using. But console Vim
users have good alternatives, such as CursorMoved and TextChanged.